# Rails has_one association, accessing associated models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I currently am experimenting with Rails model associations to get into better grips with them. Currently I have achieved what I wanted, which is having a relationship table that connects the data of two of my models together. The problem I am facing is that I have this feeling that there might be a better way to associate the tables from the ones that I currently have. To give a better explanation with the code that I currently have:

I have an Institution model which basically lets me add institution names(I am keeping the models as simple as possible until I have the correct method for doing this:

```
class Institution < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :marketings
  has_many :usermocks , through: :marketings
end
```

Then I have the user(its a mock table, no Devise or Sorcery until this is correct)

```
class Usermock < ApplicationRecord
  #has_many :marketings
  #has_many :institutions, through: :marketings
  has_one :marketing
  has_one :institution, through: :marketing
end
```

And finally, the relationship table which for now I have called marketing(I am trying to associate a list of individuals that work in a marketing department, kinda toying with building the model for institutions where I work at)

```
class Marketing < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :usermock
  belongs_to :institution
end
```

The plan is, the institution will have a set of marketers, and each marketer can only belong to one institution, hence the `has_one` helper on the `Usermock` class. It works though, if I add an institution, create a user and then pass the user to the institution it will work, my problem is that accessing the institution's data through the user needs to be done through the marketing table:

```
institution = Institution.create(institution_name: "Test Institution")
user_mock   = Usermock.create(user_name: "Test User 1")
institution.usermocks << user_mock # builds the relationship succesfully
```

The code above works, and if I wanted to show the list of users that belong inside of the marketing department in the view that represents the institution I would just go by using `@institution.usermocks` and it will give me what I wanted no problem, I can just loop like required and output the necessary fields.

But when I do this from the user's perspective:

```
user_mock.institution # Returns nil Main problem here
user_mock.marketing.institution # returns the correct information
```

As a novice in Rails, what could I do in order to better show this relationship? The fact that user_mock.institution returns nil seems to me like bad design on my part. I already went through the Rails Association Guide and even though it was efficient enough to show me that way through the required associations I am still missing this information.

I have also looked into:
[Rails has_one :through association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116017/rails-has-one-through-association)

[Rails has_one association confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22318716/rails-has-one-association-confusion)

But I am still unsure of the correct way about this, is the `user_m_one.institution` supposed to return nil and I am forced to go by `user_m_one.marketing.institution` instead?

Any pointers from y'all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you check this again ? I am getting desired result here with the same examples you have given.

Comment: @AshikSalman will give it a go right now

Comment: What does the Marketing model (and table) store (besides user and institution id)?. You could just have the institution id in the user model and don't use the Marketing model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you have setup the Marketing table with foreign key columns. The migration may looks like:

```
class CreateMarketings < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :marketings do |t|
      t.references :usermock, foreign_key: true
      t.references :institution, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Now if you query `user_mock.institution`, it will produce the following Query

```
 SELECT  "institutions".* FROM "institutions" INNER JOIN "marketings" ON "institutions"."id" = "marketings"."institution_id" WHERE "marketings"."usermock_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["usermock_id", usermock_id], ["LIMIT", 1]
```

And it will return the institution object associated with the usermock model.

Comment: This was strange. It is working now. The migration file looks exactly like that one so I had no clue why this was not working originally. I got it know. Thanks man!